# Fallback image and timeout - External Content. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fallback

What is the best way to set up a local fallback image if the external image does not load or takes too long to load.

Comment: Brilliant! I was just about to ask the same question, and I did a quick google search and found this question. I was thinking of doing it server side, but client side sounds much more straightforward.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can add an `onerror` handler:

```
<img
  src="http://example.com/somejpg.jpg"
  onerror='this.onerror = null; this.src="./oops.gif"'
/>
```

Note: Setting `onerror` to null in the handler, so that the webpage doesn't crash if `oops.gif` can't be loaded for some reason.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about onerror. This might be easier, but the solution I posted below allows to precache the images and check their availability before they have to be displayed. Depends on what you need...

Comment: Awesome! Love it when I learn new tricks like this. I was going to resort to some jQuery jiggery pokery.

Comment: The problem here is the time by which the image regarded as not available ! It may take long time the browser activity loading works till it invoke the `onerror` event.

Comment: Thank you so much. it's very fantastic

Answer (score 2):

Try to make use of the Image.complete property.

```
var img = new Image(w,h)
img.src = "http://...";
```

Now check periodically if `img.complete` is true and call some fallback mechanism shuold it still be `false` after n seconds.