# asp.net check if imageURL exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, url, imageurl

I am trying to get a user's thumbnail from another intranet site but some of them do not follow the pre-defined format meaning I would want to load up a default thumbnail instead.

Whats the best way to check if an image URL is valid?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588854/fallback-image-and-timeout-external-content-javascript there is the onerror attribute in the img tag

Comment: ^sorry I didn't see this before answering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on how you are getting your images a variation of this might work

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="<dynamic handler url>" alt="My Username" onError="this.src='defaultProfile.jpg';" />
    </body>
</html>
```

This is how you would do it in ASP.NET.

Designer -

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl="NonexistentImage.Jpg" ID="profileImage" Height="50" Width="50" runat=server />
```

Code Behind (c#)

```
profileImage.Attributes["onerror"] = "this.src='http://www.cs.uofs.edu/~olivetoj2/blah.jpg';";
```

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. the <asp:image> does not have this attribute.

Comment: you can set it by adding it to attributes collections, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx

Comment: onError doesnt seem to work for either <img> or <asp:image> it actually said onError is not a valid element of <img>

Comment: It isn't part of the w3c standard but most browsers support it.  Even back in 2001 - http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/2001Sep/0084.html.  There are a lot of people using it (http://blog.sociomantic.com/2010/07/html-onerror-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/) so it's likely to be the asp image control causing the issue.

Comment: That works perfectly. I just had some syntax errors within the string. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, probably should have put the asp.net example first.

Comment: ASP VB code behind hide image if not found. 
myImage.Attributes("onerror") = "this.style.visibility=""hidden"";"

Answer (score 2):

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);  
WebResponse webResponse;
try 
{
  webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
}
catch //If exception thrown then couldn't get response from address
{
  return 0;
} 
return 1;
```

Comment: You have forget to close the response objects and this lead to problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can acheive this in jQuery quite easily.

```
$("#myImage")
    .load(function() { alert("it loaded ok") })
    .error(function() {  $(this).attr("src", alternateImage)  });
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code-behind check

```
File.Exists(Server.MapPath("file path"))
```

If it returns true then assign the value, otherwise assign your default thumbnail.