# Show the item before uploading the photos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a form with multiple photos. They take a long time to load all images. I would like a replacement photo to be shown before uploading the photos. And then a photo from the form, if my user's browser is already loading everything.

```
<!-- Basic img -->
<img alt="Loader img" src="/home/loader/img-loader.png">

<a href="choice/1/">
  <h1>Choice field 1</h1>
  <img alt="Loader img" src="/image/1.png">
</a>
<a href="choice/2/">
  <h1>Choice field 2</h1>
  <img alt="Loader img" src="/image/2.png">
</a>
<a href="choice/3/">
  <h1>Choice field 3</h1>
  <img alt="Loader img" src="/image/3.png">
</a>
<a href="choice/4/">
  <h1>Choice field 4</h1>
  <img alt="Loader img" src="/image/4.png">
</a>
```

So until the photo is uploaded `<img alt="Loader img" src="/image/1.png"> <img alt="Loader img" src="/image/2.png"> <img alt="Loader img" src="/image/3.png"> <img alt="Loader img" src="/image/4.png">` user see  and then after loading all images by the browser, the user sees everything.

How to recive this effect using JS / jQuery or CSS / Html

Comment: Does [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588854/fallback-image-and-timeout-external-content-javascript) your question?

Comment: There's a lot of information to be found on placeholder image strategies. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can give the images a background-image via CSS, but only if they have a data-loading-attribute. When the onload event of the image triggers, remove this attribute. Adjust dimensions and image paths as needed.

```css
img[data-loading] { 
  height: 40px; 
  width: 40px; 
  background-image: url(./path/to-background-image.png); 
}
```

and in the HTML:

```html
<img alt="Loader img" src="/image/4.png" data-loading onload="this.removeAttribute('data-loading')">
```